# Tests doesnt run when specifying subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I am using minitest and whenever I try to run a directory isolated like `rake test/models`, the tests doesn't run and I get no output in console.

Any idea as to why this is?

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't define a `test/models` task.  Rake uses colons for namespacing, so what you want is: `rake test:models`.

Comment: I thought you could specifiy the path to the test folder/file that wanted to run, but your suggestion yields a 'command not found'.

Comment: No, in most cases you should be able to run a single test case by passing the name of the file to Ruby - e.g. "ruby test/models/my_model_test.rb".  But you can't pass a directory like this to Rake and expect anything to happen.

Comment: I don't understand why you're getting "command not found", but it indicates that Rake itself wasn't found.  If it were a problem with the Rake task not being found, you'd be getting something like "Don't know how to build task 'foo'".  Are you able to call just "rake" with no task specified?